Detox error after Android app opens: Failed to run application on the device
I am new to Detox and am at the point of just trying to get a basic test running successfully.
After running detox test --configuration android.emu.debug the app opens successfully, but then just hangs and eventually I get the following errors:
10:56:55.138 detox[51659] B jest --config e2e/jest.config.js
10:56:58.042 detox[51660] i Babel config: myApp sandbox debug
10:56:58.489 detox[51660] i login.test.js is assigned to emulator-5554 (Pixel_7_Pro_API_33)
11:00:07.190 detox[51660] i ToS Accept: should show ToS screen
11:00:07.202 detox[51660] i ToS Accept: should show ToS screen [FAIL]

11:00:07.301 detox[51660] i An error occurred while waiting for the app to become ready. Waiting for disconnection...
  error: Failed to run application on the device
  
  HINT: Most likely, your main activity has crashed prematurely.
  
  Native stacktrace dump:
  com.wix.detox.common.DetoxErrors$DetoxRuntimeException: Waited for the new RN-context for too long! (180 seconds)
  If you think that's not long enough, consider applying a custom Detox runtime-config in DetoxTest.runTests().
        at com.wix.detox.reactnative.ReactNativeLoadingMonitor.awaitNewRNContext(ReactNativeLoadingMonitor.kt:60)
        at com.wix.detox.reactnative.ReactNativeLoadingMonitor.getNewContext(ReactNativeLoadingMonitor.kt:29)
        at com.wix.detox.reactnative.ReactNativeExtension.awaitNewReactNativeContext(ReactNativeExtension.kt:129)
        at com.wix.detox.reactnative.ReactNativeExtension.waitForRNBootstrap(ReactNativeExtension.kt:36)
        at com.wix.detox.DetoxMain.launchActivity(DetoxMain.kt:127)
        at com.wix.detox.DetoxMain.launchActivityOnCue(DetoxMain.kt:53)
        at com.wix.detox.DetoxMain.run(DetoxMain.kt:33)
        at com.wix.detox.Detox.runTests(Detox.java:126)
        at com.wix.detox.Detox.runTests(Detox.java:93)
        at de.mcoins.mycompany.DetoxTest.runDetoxTests(DetoxTest.java:27)
  
11:00:07.362 detox[51660] i The app disconnected.
11:00:07.364 detox[51660] i The pending request #-49642 ("cleanup") has been rejected due to the following error:

The app has unexpectedly disconnected from Detox server.
 FAIL  e2e/login.test.js (191.641 s)
  ToS Accept
    ✕ should show ToS screen (7 ms)

  ● ToS Accept › should show ToS screen

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 120000 ms for a hook.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      1 | describe('ToS Accept', () => {
    > 2 |   beforeAll(async () => {
        |   ^
      3 |     await device.launchApp();
      4 |   });
      5 |

      at beforeAll (e2e/login.test.js:2:3)
      at Object.describe (e2e/login.test.js:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        191.828 s
Ran all test suites.
11:00:07.491 detox[51659] E Command failed with exit code = 1:
jest --config e2e/jest.config.js

I have looked around at previous issues like this, but everybody seemed to have something wrong with their setup. In my case I followed the Detox setup guide and I cannot see what is missing.
My detoxrc.js:
/** @type {Detox.DetoxConfig} */
module.exports = {
  testRunner: {
    args: {
      '$0': 'jest',
      config: 'e2e/jest.config.js'
    },
    jest: {
       setupTimeout: 120000
    }
  },
  apps: {
    'myApp.android.debug': {
      type: 'android.apk',
      binaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/myApp/debug/myApp-debug-v504.apk',
      testBinaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/myApp/debug/app-myApp-debug-androidTest.apk',
      build: 'cd android && ./gradlew assemblemyAppSandboxDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug',
      reversePorts: [
        8081
      ]
    }
  },
  devices: {
    attached: {
      type: 'android.attached',
      device: {
        adbName: '.*'
      }
    },
    emulator: {
      type: 'android.emulator',
      device: {
        avdName: 'Pixel_7_Pro_API_33'
      }
    }
  },
  configurations: {
    'ios.sim.debug': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.debug'
    },
    'ios.sim.release': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.release'
    },
    'android.att.debug': {
      device: 'attached',
      app: 'myApp.android.debug'
    },
    'android.att.release': {
      device: 'attached',
      app: 'android.release'
    },
    'android.emu.debug': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'myApp.android.debug'
    },
    'android.emu.release': {
      device: 'emulator',
      app: 'android.release'
    }
  }
};

My DetoxTest.java:
package com.example.myApp;

import com.wix.detox.Detox;
import com.wix.detox.config.DetoxConfig;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class DetoxTest {
    @Rule // (2)
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);

    @Test
    public void runDetoxTests() {
        DetoxConfig detoxConfig = new DetoxConfig();
        detoxConfig.idlePolicyConfig.masterTimeoutSec = 90;
        detoxConfig.idlePolicyConfig.idleResourceTimeoutSec = 60;
        detoxConfig.rnContextLoadTimeoutSec = (BuildConfig.DEBUG ? 180 : 60);

        Detox.runTests(mActivityRule, detoxConfig);
    }
}

My test suite:
describe('ToS Accept', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp();
  });

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should show ToS screen', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('TosTitle'))).toBeVisible();
  });
});


